# node.js - express - typeerror: res.json is not a function

Tags: node.js, http, express

I am trying to respond to an http request, and I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: req.json is not a function
```

Here is where I call it:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
const channel_name = req.query.channel_name;
const user_name = req.query.user_name;
const text = req.query.text;

var input = text.split(" ");
if (input[0] == "move") { // Make move

    game.move(user_name, channel_name, input[1], input[2], function(returnGame) {
        req.json(game.getGameStatus(returnGame));
    });
}
else {
    var boardSize = 3;
    if (input.length == 2)
        boardSize = input[1];
    var newGame = game.startGame(channel_name, user_name, input[0], boardSize);
    res.json(game.getGameStatus(newGame));
}
});
app.listen(port);
```

game.move and game.startGame both return a JSON called Game. StartGame creates the JSON and returns it, but move loads the JSON from a database and uses a callback to return it. 
I get the error when I call req.json from the callback, but it works fine for StartGame.

Any ideas? I've been stuck on this all day and can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing error detected at `req.json(game.getGameStatus(returnGame));`

`.json` is defined for `res`, not for `req`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I haven't slept in like 30 hours, trying to finish this thing, can't believe I missed that.......